# How to run a statement again and again on a case but on different occurrences

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, encoding, cryptography

Hey guys I am making an encoding system in which each letter gets converted into predefined gibberish.
For example, 'a' has already been set as 'ashgahsjahjs'.

But using `if a in data: print("ashgahsjahjs")` executes this for one time only, if there are more than one A in the word, it would not print them with gibberish.

Using a while loop does not work either as it keeps printing indefinitely, so is there a way to print the gibberish each time there is a new occurrence of a letter.

Answer (score 0):

you could try indexing the string.

```
your_string = "are you an apple?"
for i in range(len(your_string)):
    if "a" == your_string[i]:
        print("Found a at position {pos}".format(pos=i))
    else:
        print("Nope")
```